Reducing white space on either side of a single-bar stacked horizontal bar chart - Chart js

I am using chart js to generate this chart within a React component.
My code is as follows:
setChartData({
                labels: ['SDA300'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: `Pass (%)`,
                        data: [passValue],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(150,190,45,1)',
                        barThickness: 40,
                    },
                    {
                        label: `Fail (%)`,
                        data: [failValue],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(238,109,109, 1)',
                        barThickness: 40,
                    },
                ],
            });


const options: ChartOptions<'bar'> = {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true,
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true,
            },
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
            },
        },
    };

{chartData.labels && <Bar data={chartData} options={options} />}

I tried removing the barThickness and playing with barPercentage and categoryPercentage, but it doesn.t seem to be getting me where I want, which is reducing the white space on top and under the bar.

First, you have to set option maintainAspectRatio: false if you want to have non-standard chart sizes; then, you have to control the size of the chart - the best way is to set, through CSS, the height of an enclosing div that only contains the chart canvas. Finally, if it is not essential, drop the barThickness: 40 option - instead, set a chart height that would make the bar approximately 40px thick (e.g., 120px). See fiddle with barThickness, fiddle without barThickness.
